# Hebrew to English Translations of Daniel 9:23-27

Tags: translation, daniel-book-of

I'm kind of falling on a last resort here. I'm trying to get as close to a literal translation of the most original form of Daniel 9/I:23-27 as possible. I haven't been able to find anything in English, just these two Hebrew sources. But I can't read Hebrew :( nor have the time to learn. Would it be too much to ask if someone could translate these two sources to English for me? I wish there was a Hebrew SE; seeing as there are French, German, Japanese, and Spanish SEs. Maybe I'll suggest one. Anyway..

Here is the text from [Mechon-Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t3409.htm):

> כג בִּתְחִלַּת תַּחֲנוּנֶיךָ יָצָא דָבָר, וַאֲנִי בָּאתִי
>   לְהַגִּיד--כִּי חֲמוּדוֹת, אָתָּה; וּבִין, בַּדָּבָר, וְהָבֵן,
>   בַּמַּרְאֶה. כד שָׁבֻעִים שִׁבְעִים נֶחְתַּךְ עַל-עַמְּךָ וְעַל-עִיר
>   קָדְשֶׁךָ, לְכַלֵּא הַפֶּשַׁע ולחתם (וּלְהָתֵם) חטאות (חַטָּאת)
>   וּלְכַפֵּר עָו‍ֹן, וּלְהָבִיא, צֶדֶק עֹלָמִים; וְלַחְתֹּם חָזוֹן
>   וְנָבִיא, וְלִמְשֹׁחַ קֹדֶשׁ קָדָשִׁים. כה וְתֵדַע וְתַשְׂכֵּל
>   מִן-מֹצָא דָבָר, לְהָשִׁיב וְלִבְנוֹת יְרוּשָׁלִַם עַד-מָשִׁיחַ
>   נָגִיד--שָׁבֻעִים, שִׁבְעָה; וְשָׁבֻעִים שִׁשִּׁים וּשְׁנַיִם,
>   תָּשׁוּב וְנִבְנְתָה רְחוֹב וְחָרוּץ, וּבְצוֹק, הָעִתִּים. כו
>   וְאַחֲרֵי הַשָּׁבֻעִים שִׁשִּׁים וּשְׁנַיִם, יִכָּרֵת מָשִׁיחַ וְאֵין
>   לוֹ; וְהָעִיר וְהַקֹּדֶשׁ יַשְׁחִית עַם נָגִיד הַבָּא, וְקִצּוֹ
>   בַשֶּׁטֶף, וְעַד קֵץ מִלְחָמָה, נֶחֱרֶצֶת שֹׁמֵמוֹת. כז וְהִגְבִּיר
>   בְּרִית לָרַבִּים, שָׁבוּעַ אֶחָד; וַחֲצִי הַשָּׁבוּעַ יַשְׁבִּית
>   זֶבַח וּמִנְחָה, וְעַל כְּנַף שִׁקּוּצִים מְשֹׁמֵם, וְעַד-כָּלָה
>   וְנֶחֱרָצָה, תִּתַּךְ עַל-שֹׁמֵם. {פ}

And here is the text from [Wikisource](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%98/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91):

> כג בתחלת תחנוניך יצא דבר ואני באתי להגיד כי חמודות אתה ובין בדבר והבן
>   במראה כד שבעים שבעים נחתך על עמך ועל עיר קדשך לכלא הפשע ולחתם חטאות
>   [ולהתם חטאת] ולכפר עון ולהביא צדק עלמים ולחתם חזון ונביא ולמשח קדש
>   קדשים כה ותדע ותשכל מן מצא דבר להשיב ולבנות ירושלם עד משיח נגיד שבעים
>   שבעה ושבעים ששים ושנים תשוב ונבנתה רחוב וחרוץ ובצוק העתים כו ואחרי
>   השבעים ששים ושנים יכרת משיח ואין לו והעיר והקדש ישחית עם נגיד הבא וקצו
>   בשטף ועד קץ מלחמה נחרצת שממות כז והגביר ברית לרבים שבוע אחד וחצי השבוע
>   ישבית זבח ומנחה ועל כנף שקוצים משמם ועד כלה ונחרצה תתך על שמם

Comment: Found this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage. Help support it if you'd like :)

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/162/759 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/660/759

Comment: @Shredder, the Hebrew texts you've pasted are identical. Mechon-Mamre and Wikisource both use the Masoratic text, as far as I know. There's no need for both. Also, I'm not sure what you expect to gain asking the question here over [asking it](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/accurate-translations-of-original-scripts-text) on Hermeneutics.SE. We have already established that translations without bias are impossible....

Comment: ...It seems to me that here you will merely get a translation biased toward a Jewish interpretation of the verses. If yoiu ask the question on Christianity.SE, you will likely get one biased toward a Christian interpretation. Altogether, you are gaining nothing that cannot already be found easily online.

Comment: @jake Well I'm not getting much help on Hermeneutics. Was thinking since lots of community members here know Hebrew, I could get a little more help.

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0.htm

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13294, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40888.

Answer (score 3):

translation here

http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16492

and scholarly links translations here:

http://www.bible-researcher.com/links02.html

Comment: I don't think he likes that translation http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13301/732

Comment: Thanks for your response simchashatorah :) I'm interested if there is any other input to compare this with. Thx again!

Comment: Interesting how it uses the word "king" and not "prince", like I've seen in most other translations.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a literal translation with no care for phrases, or implied context. However grammatical tense has mostly been removed because I'm not sure which grammar system is used in Daniel. If there is any word I mistranslated, please correct me.

---

בִּתְחִלַּת תַּחֲנוּנֶיךָ יָצָא דָבָר, וַאֲנִי בָּאתִי לְהַגִּיד--כִּי חֲמוּדוֹת, אָתָּה; וּבִין, בַּדָּבָר, וְהָבֵן, בַּמַּרְאֶה.

In start (supplication/pettition) exit (thing/word), and I in my to tell because sweet thing you, and understand the (thing/word) and actively understand in showing.

שָׁבֻעִים שִׁבְעִים נֶחְתַּךְ עַל-עַמְּךָ וְעַל-עִיר קָדְשֶׁךָ, לְכַלֵּא הַפֶּשַׁע ולחתם (וּלְהָתֵם) חטאות (חַטָּאת) וּלְכַפֵּר עָו‍ֹן, וּלְהָבִיא, צֶדֶק עֹלָמִים; וְלַחְתֹּם חָזוֹן וְנָבִיא, וְלִמְשֹׁחַ קֹדֶשׁ קָדָשִׁים.

70 weeks, (without vowels this can be 70 70 or weeks weeks, it all depends on the vowels) 
This next word I'm not sure how to translate. It could be a form of in the future suplication/pettion to you, or the word could mean cut. 
continuing on...  On your nation and on city that is holy, to curse crime/sin/vice/missdeed and to **written it says seal, and read it says to go there. or visa versa 
**written is says your sins, read it says your sin. or visa versa
and to pardon your "inequities" and to come righteous worlds/forever;
And to seal the vision/prophecy/revelation and prophet, to anoint the Holy of Holies.

וְתֵדַע וְתַשְׂכֵּל מִן-מֹצָא דָבָר, לְהָשִׁיב וְלִבְנוֹת יְרוּשָׁלִַם עַד-מָשִׁיחַ נָגִיד--שָׁבֻעִים, שִׁבְעָה; וְשָׁבֻעִים שִׁשִּׁים וּשְׁנַיִם, תָּשׁוּב וְנִבְנְתָה רְחוֹב וְחָרוּץ, וּבְצוֹק, הָעִתִּים.

And know and understand from finding word/thing, to mark and to hearts, Jeruselem until the anointed comes 70/weeks 7.  And 70/weeks 60 and 2 return and built street and moat, and cliff/rock/crag the times in future.

וְאַחֲרֵי הַשָּׁבֻעִים שִׁשִּׁים וּשְׁנַיִם, יִכָּרֵת מָשִׁיחַ וְאֵין לוֹ; וְהָעִיר וְהַקֹּדֶשׁ יַשְׁחִית עַם נָגִיד הַבָּא, וְקִצּוֹ בַשֶּׁטֶף, וְעַד קֵץ מִלְחָמָה, נֶחֱרֶצֶת שֹׁמֵמוֹת.

And after 70/weeks 60 and 2, will cut anointed and nothing to him.  And city and holy corrupt nation governor/prince/ruler/chancellor/leader/commander/rector to come and cut fluently and until end of war cuts  wastes

וְהִגְבִּיר בְּרִית לָרַבִּים, שָׁבוּעַ אֶחָד; וַחֲצִי הַשָּׁבוּעַ יַשְׁבִּית זֶבַח וּמִנְחָה, וְעַל כְּנַף שִׁקּוּצִים מְשֹׁמֵם, וְעַד-כָּלָה וְנֶחֱרָצָה, תִּתַּךְ עַל-שֹׁמֵם. {פ}

And a strong one contract to many, week one; and half week  will disable Zevach(a type of animal sacrifice) and Mincha (a type of flour sacrifice) and on corners that are thorns from the name/desolate/infertile/devastated/forsaken, and until bride/extermination(it can mean both), and inevitable clipped on the name/desolate/infertile/devastated/forsaken noun.

---

This should give you a good understanding of why you can't translate without interpretation, and can't give a true literal translation.  It should also give you all the information you know to construct your own translation that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Like [avi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13398/9682) pointed out, the Book of Daniel uses a grammatically awkward version of both Hebrew and Aramaic throughout its entirety. Thus, my translation below is that of [Sefaria](http://sefaria.org/Daniel.9.22-27) (with slight punctuation and spelling fixes on my part).

In verses 9:1-19, Daniel describes how, in light of nearing the end of the prophecy of Seventy Years, he prayed to God for the redemption of the Jewish People. In verses 20-21, he tells how, during this prayer, the angel ("man") Gabriel was sent to speak with him. Gabriel begins speaking in the middle of verse 22 (and, I repeat, is not a literal translation):

> **(22)** He made me understand by speaking to me and saying, "Daniel, I have just come forth to give you understanding.
>
> **(23)** A word went forth as you began your plea, and I have come to tell it, for you are precious; so mark the word and understand the vision.
>
> **(24)** Seventy weeks have been decreed for your people and your holy city until the measure of transgression is filled and that of sin complete, until iniquity is expiated, and eternal righteousness ushered in, and prophetic vision ratified, and the Holy of Holies anointed.
>
> **(25)** You must know and understand: from the issuance of the word to restore and rebuild Jerusalem until the [time of the] anointed leader is seven weeks, and for sixty-two weeks it will be rebuilt, square and moat, but in a time of distress.
>
> **(26)** And after those sixty-two weeks, the anointed one will disappear and vanish. The army of a leader who is to come will destroy the city and the sanctuary, but its end will come through a flood. Desolation is decreed until the end of the war.
>
> **(27)** During one week he will make a firm covenant with many. For half a week he will put a stop to the sacrifice and the meal offering. At the corner [of the Altar] will be an appalling abomination until the decreed destruction will be poured down upon the appalling thing."

Rashi (to verse 24) explains that, in response to Daniel's plea regarding the rebuilding of the Second Temple, he was given a message that detailed the events from the destruction of the First Temple to the destruction of the Second. He also notes throughout the passage that "weeks" refers to 7-year cycles, not 7-day cycles.

The Book of Daniel is also written out of order, so when the chapter ends after this passage, we have no idea what Daniel's response is; it jumps back in time two kings for the next chapter.