# The media in Shushan

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Esther 10:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3310.htm) says:

> הֲלוֹא-הֵם כְּתוּבִים, עַל-סֵפֶר דִּבְרֵי הַיָּמִים, לְמַלְכֵי מָדַי
> Behold, they are written in the book of chronicles of the kings of the media.

Who were the kings (=editors) of the newspapers in Shushan? What were the names of their newspapers? What positions did they lean towards on various political issues?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Yay!! It's time! :)

Comment: Didn't you mean to say _"the kings of Media and Press"_ ?

Comment: Well obviously Mordechai was Ish Yemini, a right-winger

Comment: @SethJ, you mean _Time_?

Comment: @Shalom Interesting that we both came to the same conclusion: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25652/translation-of#comment56913_25653

Answer (score 8):

We know Shushan was a walled city. Therefore, it's not unreasonable to say that their newspaper was the Wall Street Journal.

Comment: וירכבהו ברחוב העיר we see the city had a street too!

Answer (score 6):

One might have been the [Utne Reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utne_Reader). See the Targum on Esther (8:8): "And Utne, hurry, write about the Jews whatever you want in the name of the king."

> ואתן סרהיבו כתובו בגין יהודאין כד שפיר בעיניכון בשום מימרא דמלכא

Not an unusual standard for journalists, historically speaking.

Another possibility is [Horse & Rider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_%26_Rider) (ibid. 8:10): "And he sent magazines by those who hurry on horses."

Comment: Aha, I had thought [the Horse and Rider were thrown into the sea.](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.15.21?lang=he-en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all)

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that the head of the media empire in Shushan was none other than [Shetar](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3301.htm#14), whose name clearly derives from the word for [a document](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/legal-documents/synonyms).