# How were the Jews able to eat Haman?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Shemot (Exodus) 16:35 says:

> ובני ישראל אכלו את המן ארבעים שנה
>
> The children of Israel ate Haman for 40 years

My questions:

- Even though there is a commandment to destroy Amalek, and Haman was an Amelekite, there is also a prohibition of eating human flesh as humans aren't kosher. Was Haman an exception? Was he kosher, or if not, why were they allowed to eat Haman despite his not being kosher?
- They ate Haman for 40 years. The Torah says that the population of males over 20 was around 600 thousand, and that remained fairly constant throughout the 40 years in the desert. If you factor the children and women, there area a lot more than that number. How large was Haman that he was able to be sufficient food for so many people for 40 years? How did he become so large?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Previously on PTIJ: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14923/haman-was-basar-b-chalav-so-how-could-we-eat-him

Comment: That's not the same Haman! As per [the gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=139b&format=pdf), Haman is in [Genesis 3:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.11)

Comment: @IsaacMoses Duplicate?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I can change the scope of the question even though I'm using the same verse. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @Shokhet and DanF I guess it's not technically a duplicate, since the particular problems raised are different; I think this is an area of PTIJ jurisprudence that is still developing as our body of existing PTIJ grows and ages.

Comment: "How did he become so large?" See Esther 3:1. Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26143

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps we can answer this by looking at a different question. Even though Haman clearly had *basar*, the passuk says in Esther *vayimalei Haman cheima* so he was also filled with butter. Thus, Jews eating him in the desert seemingly violated eating *basar bechalav*.

To solve this, it could only have been possible if (a) Haman was a fish and (b) they were paskening like the Rama against the Shulchan Aruch with allows to eat fish with milchigs.

(a) Also helps to understand why he had a son named Dalphon, a prehistoric form of *dolphin*.

That they had enough of him to eat for 40 years can be explained from a Targum Yonason which says he was hanging on the gallows with his children together, so that means he was hung there for 11 months from Pesach to Purim and did not decompose. So we see his body was the place of appearance of a miracle and hence one should not wonder why it was enough - like *lechem hapanim* even a small amount would be enough to feed a person for a long while and in addition, he eaten portions were replenished miraculously every night. This replenishment ability manifested again after his hanging to keep him from decomposing for 11 months.

This also explains why it was allowed to put pieces of him in or near the aron kodesh which normally would be *assur* since they are *tamei* -- but because of this miraculous replenishing ability, the *bracha* constantly rested on them, and hence they were always in a state of *tahara*