# PTIJ: Where / how can I buy Human Taschen?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

A friend sent me this picture of Human Taschen:

[image: Human Taschen]

I see that it has two kashrut symbols. I find the CRC reliable. I can't quite read what the second kashrut symbol is.

I've looked in a few stores in the New York City area, but no one carries it. Someone referred me to a website called "Twilight Zone", as it has a division called [To Serve Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_%28The_Twilight_Zone%29). I couldn't find a web site for this Twilight Zone.

The product says it's "amazing", and, I'd imagine that it is. They look tasty from the picture! But, I can't find this product. Maybe, because this is made from humans this is a secret family recipe?

Please refer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80889/5275), which, indirectly explains what might make this product kosher considering that you're eating a human.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: “Home taste” I’m not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @DonielF I had the same curiosity. Thus, my ending assumption that this must be a secret family recipe, and that may be the reason why I can't find this.

Comment: When you find out where it's made, buy me some too. Human is next on my exotic kosher food bucket list, right after locusts and before giraffes.

Comment: Joking aside, how does a regular-sized box of hamantashen cost $15?

Answer (score 4):

Hannibal's Bakery, on Avenue C, carries these and other delightful Human treats. Beware, however, that they are Basari.

Comment: Do you get paid for this sort of advertising? ;)

Comment: Hannibal or Cannibal?

Comment: @Harel, sadly, my commisions are paid out entirely in kosher Chianti and fava beans

Comment: Life in Peru must be getting to you, huh?

Comment: @DanF BH I've been at a yeshiva on Har Tzion learning for a month now, life in Peru is a distant memory

Comment: @JoshK BH, indeed! Good for you and for us. Much *hatzlacha*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you can get them at the bakery down in Tashi Station, next door to that place that sells power converters.

(I haven't actually checked them out, due to the issues raised e.g. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30683/9589), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64985/9589), and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9250/9589).)